# Test Lambda Locally (Lambda function calling another lambda function)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-architecture

I am learning node and serverless architecture. 
To test my lambda function locally I am currently using [lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local) which has been working fine so far.

Now I have a function that [invoke](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) another lambda function, something like this:

```
    let lambda = new integration.myLambda.AWS.Lambda();
    let params = {
        FunctionName: 'my-other-function',
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        LogType: 'None',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(myEvent)
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        lambda.invoke(params, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('error on invoke', error);
                reject({
                    statusCode: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    message: error
                });

            } else {
                console.log('invoke success', data);
                resolve(JSON.parse(data.Payload));
            }
        });

    });
```

This bit of code does not work locally, but once deployed on aws it's working fine. However deploying to aws it takes about 2 mins. So I was wondering if there is a way to have this code run locally.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: From my 2 years experience with AWS Lambda - I assume you'd like to run them locally in order to unit test them.

There are several ways of unit testing AWS Lambda's locally.
In this post, they describe one that I have been using and I can recommend: https://blog.atomdata.io/serverless-applications-continuous-delivery-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-part-1-unit-tests-e517aa1cd09e

Comment: I am currently in a similar situation... did you ever find a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So personally I use [serverless](https://serverless.com) as my preferred framework for local, there's also a very promising looking project from atlassian called localstack [here](https://github.com/atlassian/localstack) - I haven't actually tried the second one! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I find out that all I need it to do was to export:
 accessKeyId and secretAccessKey.

Just for testing put it in code just above your invoke call. Then make sure you set them in a secure place.

I was exporting them

```
export ACCESS_KEY_ID=yourkey

export SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yoursecretkey
```

Now I am using docker so I have them in a config file.

Hope this helps